# Pulling a timestamp from an XML feed with PHP but seem to be to many digits

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, epoch

I am pulling a timestamp from a feed and it gives 12 digits (1269088723811). When I convert it, it comes out as

1901-12-13 20:45:52,

but if I put the timestamp into http://www.epochconverter.com/ it comes out as

Sat, 20 Mar 2010 12:38:43 GMT, which is the correct time.

epochconverter.com mentions that it maybe in milliseconds so I have amended the script to take care of it using

`$mil = $timestamp;

$seconds = $mil / 1000;

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', date($seconds));`

but it still converts the date wrong, 1970-01-25 20:31:23.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a trimmed [microtime()](http://de3.php.net/microtime) output. The only thing you seem to be doing wrong is using `date($seconds)` instead of the raw `$seconds`. Try

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $seconds);
```

Comment: Whats the best way to script it?

Comment: Umm, how is removing the last three digits different from dividing by 1000?

Comment: I have tried using $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $seconds); but it still comes out as 1970-01-25 20:31:23, in fact the feed contains multiple items which each have a time stamp, even though the timestamp is different for each one the date on each is 1970-01-25 20:31:23.

Comment: @Craig that's hard to believe. I am suspecting the incoming timestamps have a non-numeric character in them. Are you 100% sure they look like you posted them? WHat happens if you do a `$mil = (int)$timestamp;`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo><a>1269088723811</a></foo>');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (float)$xml->a / 1000);
```

and

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo><a>1269088723811</a></foo>');
$ts = substr($xml->a, 0, -3);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
```

both print `2010-03-20 07:38:43` (on my Europe/Berlin machine)

Comment: Talking about SimpleXml quirks again ;)

Comment: Hi Guys, 

Managed to get it working using

`$timestamp = $xml->entry[$i]->attributes('http://www.google.com/schemas/reader/atom/')->{'crawl-timestamp-msec'};
 $tsmod = substr($timestamp, 0, -3);
 $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $tsmod);`

Cheers for all the help guys